# Euler's $\phi$ function is multiplicative, help with my proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, totient-function

Euler's $\phi$ function is multiplicative

We define $U_k = \{x\in Z_k \;| \;(x,k)=1\}$ So clearly $\phi(k)=|U_k|$

Let $(m,n)=1$

Want to show : $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\cdot \phi(n)$ or $|U_{mn}|=|U_m|\cdot |U_n|$

I want to produce a bijection from $U_{mn} \to U_m \times U_n$

I define $$f:U_{mn} \to U_m \times U_n$$

$$f(a \pmod{mn}) =  (a \pmod{m}, \;a\pmod{n}) \;\; \forall a\in U_{mn}$$

Note that for $a,b\in U_{mn}$, we have $a=b \iff  a \pmod {mn} = b\pmod{mn}$

so let $a,b\in U_{mn}$ such that $a \pmod{mn} =b \pmod{mn} \rightarrow a=b $, 
then,

$f(a \pmod{mn}) =  (a \pmod{m}, \;a\pmod{n}) = (b \pmod{m}, \;b\pmod{n}) = f(b \pmod{mn})$. So it is well defined.

Also, if $f(a \pmod{mn}) =f(b \pmod{mn})$ for some $a,b \in U_{mn}$

$\rightarrow (a \pmod{m}, \;a\pmod{n}) = (b \pmod{m}, \;b\pmod{n})$

$\rightarrow a \pmod{m}= b \pmod{m}$ and $a\pmod{n} =b\pmod{n}$

$\rightarrow a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $a\equiv b\pmod n$

Because $(m,n)=1$

$\rightarrow a\equiv b \pmod{mn}$

$\rightarrow a \pmod {mn} = b\pmod{mn}$

$\rightarrow a=b$ because $a,b \in U_{mn}$

So it is injective.

Now let $(a,b) \in U_m \times U_n$

$\rightarrow a\in U_m$ and $b\in U_n$

$\rightarrow (a,m)=1$ and $(b,n)=1$

$now \exists ab \pmod{mn} \in U_{mn}$

such that $f((ab \pmod{mn}) \pmod{mn}) = f(ab \pmod{mn}) = (ab \pmod m, ab\pmod n) = ?$ (Getting stuck here, help please)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By *Bezout's identity* there are $x, y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $xm+yn=1$.
Use $x, y$ to express a number $s$ that satisfies $s\equiv a\pmod m$ and $s\equiv b\pmod m$.

Comment: I am unable to arrive at it. can you tell me?

Comment: We have $b=bxm+byn\equiv bxm\pmod n$ and $a=axm+ayn\equiv ayn\pmod m$. Then let $s:=ayn+bxm$.